# fatal: cannot open file `counters' for reading (No such file or directory)"

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying use the awk to read numbers total integer (total=*****) numbers in a system counter file which contains alphanumeric characters, without piping the result to another command.

i.e.:

```
TCP time wait closed (net): 0 (total=0)
TCP gc closed (net): 0 (total=0)
TCP internal closed (net): 0 (total=0)
192.168.254.2:80 sockets (cpu0) (knet): 0 / 0 (total=0)
```

At first I tried:

```
awk -F "total=" '{print $2 }'` counters
```

which resulted in:

```
0)
0)
0)
0)
```

The issue is the ")" character, which will lead to a system read error, as it's not numerical. Then I pipe the first awk result to this:

```
awk -F '[^0-9]+' '{OFS=" "; for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != "") print($i)}'
```

to read only numerical. This results in:

```
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

It worked fine in bash. However, the system I'm using did not understand the pipe in the fist awk argument, and if I config this it will result in the following error:

```
awk -F "total=" '{print $2 }' counters | awk -F '[^0-9]+' '{OFS=" "; for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != "") print($i)}`' 

awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `counters' for reading (No such file or directory)"
```

Any idea how to write a single awk that can extract the numerical numbers in (total=*)?

Comment: Are you sure the `counters` file is there, by this name? Or what exactly is your problem? You're saying `"*I worked fine in bash. However the system i'm using did not understand the pipe in the fist awk argument and if i config this it will result in the following error....*"`. So, are you trying to use bash or not?

Comment: There is a backtick in that command line. Remove it

Comment: or just `awk -F "total=" '{sub("[\)]","",$2) ; print $2}'` should suffice. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> Any idea how can write a single awk that can extract the numerical
>   numbers in (total=*) ?

If you could use [[ GNU awk ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), below script :

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/.*total=(.*)\)/,"\\1","1",$0);print}' file
```

should do it.

**Sample Run**

```
$ cat 38081612
TCP time wait closed (net): 0 (total=21)
TCP gc closed (net): 0 (total=28)
TCP internal closed (net): 0 (total=45)
192.168.254.2:80 sockets (cpu0) (knet): 0 / 0 (total=100)
$  awk '{print gensub(/.*total=(.*)\)/,"\\1","1",$0)}'  file
21
28
45
100
```

---

The awk [[ user guide ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) says `gensub()` provides the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components and then specifying ‘\N’ in the replacement text.

In short, in a record, we replace

```
(anything)total=(interested_value)ending_parenthesis
```

with

```
(interested_value)
```

and prints the result.

**Using sed**, you get a more portable solution :

```
$ sed -E 's/.*total=(.*)\)/\1/' 38081612 
21
28
45
100
```

Sed also provides the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text ie (`\1`) here.